# add a button in a tableview cell iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

I have this problem ...
I want to put my button in a cell of my table
view .. I do this ..

```
UIButton *dowMapBt = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [dowMapBt setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.frame.size.width, 70)];
        [dowMapBt setTitle:@"Download Map" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        dowMapBt.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:20];

        [dowMapBt setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"00670_btn_green_medium.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:10.0 topCapHeight:0.0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [dowMapBt addTarget:self action:@selector(ButtonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:dowMapBt];
```

but I have a problem .. the button does not appear in all
cell, but only in a half .. and not for the entire width of the cell ...

Comment: What is your cell's width and height?

Answer (score 1):

Set frame like this

```
  [dowMapBt setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.height)];
```

And also check the size of the image you are setting

Answer (score 0):

Just Add button as a subview of cell after creating cell.First check if cell is nil or not.

```
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    [dowMapBt setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.frame.size.width, 30)];
    [dowMapBt addTarget:self action:@selector(ButtonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell addSubview:dowMapBt];
}
```

Ater this return cell